# Pythonic way to write outputs of a script in gzipped file (windows)

Tags: python, file, pipe, gzip

I have a python script which prints many lines to the stdout using the command:

```
sys.stdout.write(...)
```

I would like to write those strings serially to a gzipped file, meaning at the end what should be executed is:

```
python3 myscript.py | gzip > data_out.txt
```

Comment: In your title you ask for a pythonci way but in the body, you want something on the shell level? Please clarifiy: Do you want to replace the `stdout.write()` with something that prints to a gzip file or do you want to redirect stdout?

Comment: @FlyingTeller both ways would probably suit, I just have a lot of printings so I look for some way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have added text in some variable while i am throwing on console and finally would have created gzip file out of that temp variable, would have used gzip package:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('data_out.gz', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(temp_str) #assuming temp_str contains text
```

Comment: you can encode text it if does not and open the file in binary mode

Comment: When I do this several strings are added when I open the gzipped file, for example 'aaa' will appear as b'aaa\r\n'. Can this be avoided?

Comment: could you try:
"
with gzip.open('data_out.gz', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(temp_str.encode())
"

As i don't have windows, hence not able to reproduce